# Android WebView, loading pages one by one - caching issues

Tags: android, caching, webview

I am trying to load several html pages / css files / images one by one in the android WebView: I created one WebView component, use loadURL to load a file and register WebViewClient with overloaded onPageFinished, where I get another URL from the list and ask WebView to load it. However, I ran into some caching issues: it seems that onPageFinished is invoked earlier than I need and loaded files are not cached - in another request, using only cached file, I get old version of the page. When I added Thread.sleep(2000) before loading another URL, the page is cached properly. Is there another callback function which would guarantee that I will not interrupt caching process with next loadURL invocation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mWebView.clearHistory();
mWebView.clearFormData();
mWebView.clearCache(true);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Comment: Yes - I do it exactly that way - but the problem is different: onPageFinished is invoked before cache is updated.

Comment: I went back and looked over some of my code and I updated the snippet with 2 more settings. Give it another try... this helped when I had issues with caching.